# Where is the log4j javadoc jar hiding?

Tags: jar, log4j, javadoc

It's not in apache-log4j-1.2.15.tar.gz available from the Apache website and the mirrors, and Google returns nothing. Apache Commons Lang had a javadoc jar within the tar.gz file for the release, but no luck finding the same inside the log4j tarball unfortunately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can download it [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/) and associate them with the binaries in your IDE to view the Javadoc.

Comment: Maven.org, I would have never guessed that, Apache is vast now. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

If you're ready to move to 1.2.16 you can download the log4j javadoc in a jar from the maven repo, here:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16-javadoc.jar

Also, a good resource for locating javadocs is jarvana: http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/doc

/ Papa Freud

Answer (score 0):

Generating it manually works but is a hassle.